# Can I catch discord Dyno bot message and auto reply to it?

Tags: discord, bots

As title, my scenario is:

Periodically checking if new messages were sent by Dyno bot to specific channel, and reply to it automatically.

Is it possible?

[update1]
Here are some cases:

- select the right option based one the message sent by bot
- click the right button based one the message sent by bot

[update2]
add some figures. something like these:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific: I don't even know what programming language you want to be used.

Comment: Hi, please check the update. I prefer Python or JavaScript. Low-code\no-code solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using `discord.py`, you can check if a message is written by a bot and reply to it with:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(self, message): #call the on_message() function
    if (message.author.bot): #check if the author is a bot
        await message.reply('Hello, bot!') #reply to the bot
```

Comment: thanks for your opinion. I add  some figures. Can discordPY meets my requirements?

Comment: Yea, try adding these